# Why does setting NFS sync option for AWS EFS cause nginx/Chrome to chunk or break a file upload?

Tags: nginx, upload, google-chrome, amazon-efs

**Question:** Why does an NFS mount using the `sync` option cause nginx and/or Chrome (and *only* Chrome; not Safari, Firefox, Edge or curl) to chunk or restart the file upload?

**Some background:**

I have nginx in front of a server cluster. We added file uploading and we're using nginx to handle the upload and then pass the [uploaded file body via its X-FILE header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429470/nginx-file-upload-with-client-body-in-file-only).

Until recently we were only processing uploads on the nginx server, due to the issues with other application servers in the cluster being unable to access the `client_body_temp_path` (`/tmp` in this case).

We run on AWS, so I provisioned an [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) (aka NFS) share and mounted this at `/mnt/efs` and then changed nginx `client_body_temp_path` to point at `/mnt/efs/tmp`.

I mounted the NFS share on all the application servers and they can now access the file uploads on `/mnt/efs/tmp`, *but* the uploaded files are often zero-length when they're initially read by the other clients, due to the NFS asynchronous writes.

I changed the NFS mount just on the nginx server so it's mounted with `sync`:

Initial mount:

```
example.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:/ /mnt/efs nfs4 vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport,_netdev,nofail
```

New mount:

```
example.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:/ /mnt/efs nfs4 vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport,_netdev,nofail,sync
```

I remounted the share and tried some uploads and happy days, the other NFS clients see the non-empty files in `/mnt/efs/tmp`.

But with some more testing it turns out that uploaded files over about 10M get *restarted or chunked by Chrome*.

**What happens:**

nginx starts to receive the upload ([in the video below](http://jay.gooby.org/media/video/chrome%20failing.mp4), I'm sending a 32.7MB file), but at 6.4MB, a new upload starts and then eventually nginx decides that the client's stopped sending, so issues [a `499`](https://httpstatuses.com/499) which causes Chrome to abort the upload and it all fails. You can see all this happening here, as I `watch` the files coming in to `/mnt/efs/tmp`:

http://jay.gooby.org/media/video/chrome%20failing.mp4

The upload initially comes in as `0000000006` but then when it gets to 6.4M, a second upload `0000000007` starts (but `0000000006` continues to 12M), and then when `0000000007` hits 6.4, a third, `0000000008` starts (`0000000007` continues to 12M). Once `0000000008` hits 12M ngingx issues the `499` and Chrome aborts the upload.

**Other useragents don't have this problem. I'm able to upload the same file with Safari, Firefox and curl.** Chrome on Mac and Windows both have the same issue.

Here's curl sending the file with no problems: it arrives as `0000000010` single 32M file:

http://jay.gooby.org/media/video/curl%20working.mp4

After tearing my hair out for a bit, I removed the `sync` option from the NFS mount on the nginx server and lo and behold, files uploaded with Chrome arrive in one piece as a single file. So what gives?

nginx is behind an Elastic IP, but not an ELB, and the upload is over http2.

nginx is compiled with `--with-threads` option

**Update 1:**
That 6.4mb value seemed significant, as that's the point that each new upload chunk began/restarted. 6.4mb is 51200000 bits which seems like a quite specific value...

The initial bytes of the three files are identical, so it's as if Chrome decided to start resending at the 6.4mb point:

[image: 3 identical mp4 file headers]